# How to center one element and place the second element next to it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-row

In my layout I have two Widgets in a row, a text and a button.

How can I achieve something like below, where only the Text is centered, and the icon is simply next to it?

```
---------------------------
           Text *          
---------------------------
```

Using Row would center all the contents and would output something like

```
---------------------------
          Text *           
---------------------------
```

Tried: `Row(children:[widget1, widget2], mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center);`
But this centers both items, causing the text to look off-centered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CompositedTransformTarget` and `CompositedTransformFollower` as mentioned on comment section by pskink.

```dart
class AppPT extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppPT({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                child: CompositedTransformTarget(
                  link: _layerLink,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 60,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text("btn"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              CompositedTransformFollower(
                link: _layerLink,
                targetAnchor: Alignment.centerRight,
                followerAnchor: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                  width: 12,
                  height: 12,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("*"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There are few tricks I can think of,

- You can use Stack widget with Position.
- including another widget on right by applying opacity(invisible) on current snippet.
- using transform will be handle if you know the width of the widget.

```dart
Transform.translate(
  offset: Offset(20 / 2, 0), //20 is the * box size
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 100,
        height: 60,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text("btn"),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        child: Center(child: Text("*")),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: no tricks needed: use `CompositedTransformTarget` and `CompositedTransformFollower` - both inside a `Stack` or similar multi child container (also `CustomMultiChildLayout` can be used but it requires additional delegate class to be implemented)

Comment: So many widgets thanks but one more thing, is it possible to set the `CompositedTransformFollower` centerRight without setting offset.

Comment: My text is dynamic, it can even go over two lines meaning that I'm wrapping it in a Flexible().
Is there a way to achieve it without transform and stack, but using row properties?

Comment: see `followerAnchor` / `targetAnchor`

Comment: one note: `followerAnchor` should be center left and you don't need any offset: basically target's center right point will be the same as follower's center left point - try to experiment with different follower anchors and it will clear any doubts

Answer (score -1):

Place text and second widget inside row then put the row inside container with alignment center and use SizedBox for spacing between widget instead of Padding Widget.

```
Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: 100,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: const [
          Text("Text"),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Text("*"),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly  it doesn't solve OP's issue, centered widget is not really centered in your exemple (it get's slightly to the left)